# Why can't I see the serial plot with the following code for arduino?

Tags: arduino-nano

```
const int GSR=A0;
int threshold=0;
int sensorValue;

void setup(){
  long sum=0;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

  for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
  {
  sensorValue=analogRead(GSR);
  sum += sensorValue;
  delay(5);
  }
  threshold = sum/500;
   Serial.print("threshold =");
   Serial.println(threshold);
  }

void loop(){
  int temp;
  sensorValue=analogRead(GSR);
  Serial.print("sensorValue=");
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  temp = threshold - sensorValue;
  }
```

Comment: In what way are you attempting to "plot" it? I see data arriving on serial fine.

Comment: "serial plotter" command

Comment: Maybe you should get rid of the "sensorValue=" cruft and just prinln() the value? I have never used that plotter so not sure how it handles the data, but from what I have read it just wants raw numbers.

Comment: what does cruft mean?

Comment: "badly designed, unnecessarily complicated, or unwanted code or software."

Comment: so you're reffering to "sensorValue=analogRead(GSR)"?

Comment: No, I'm referring to `Serial.print("sensorValue=");`

Comment: I will try to delete it. Plan B?

Comment: it works! Any idea on how I can save the data and bring it to excel?

Comment: Use a terminal emulator that can save the incoming data to a text file.

Comment: I'm trying coolTerm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The serial plotter requires just numbers and nothing else.

It can't understand the data in the format:

```
sensorValue=49
```

It just expects:

```
49
```

Remove the line

```
Serial.print("sensorValue=");
```

and it will start working.

Comment: I didn't understand how much readings it takes in a second. It's 1000milliseconds/ delay (=5) = 200?

Comment: It takes as many readings as it can. You have no timing specified, so the number of samples will be defined by the speed of the serial data, and the quantity of the serial data. The quantity of the serial data depends on the values being sampled.

Comment: How can I specify the timing?

Comment: Either with `delay()` (crude), `millis()` (pretty good) or a timer (most accurate).

Comment: I don't understand how to use the timer. Which kind of argument does it accept?

Comment: Timers are hard. Stick to `millis()`. Look at **BlinkWithoutDelay** for an example.

Comment: You haven't looked at **BlinkWithoutDelay**, have you?

Comment: I don't understand why it uses 3 variables for one function. Is there an easier way to do it? I

Comment: Um.... I am sorry, but I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: const long interval = 1000;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
 if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

Comment: It has been written in long hand so you can understand what is going on. You can do it with just one variable to store the timestamp - the rest is just the millis() function or a simple numeric literal.

Comment: Why do you use dalay is crode and that millis is better?

Comment: Delay doesn't take into account the time taken to perform the sampling and send it through serial, so you get clock drift. Millis takes that time into account so you don't get clock drift.

Comment: so the best way to make 4hz of sampling is with millis?

Comment: It's a good compromise between the simplicity and inaccuracy of `delay` and the accuracy and difficulty of use of using a timer.

Comment: Still, even seeing the example and this page 
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Millis
I don't know how to use it in my case

Comment: It's not exactly a difficult concept - `millis()` gives you the time. If you know what the time was the last time you ran your sample routine, and you know what the time is now, you can know when you should run your sample routine next.